# AJAX, how to return file name?

Tags: php, ajax

I Want to get a file name from recursive AJAX, but until now its doesnt work, in my code was like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>GET NAME</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<script src="/assets/mediaelements/build/jquery.js"></script>   
<script src="/assets/mediaelements/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link  href="/assets/mediaelements/build/mediaelementplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

(function rekurse(){

   setTimeout(function()
   {
        /* ---------------------------------- */

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,           
            url: 'shift.php',
            data: {offi: 'E:/DataText/OFFICE/BI/FAR1'},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
                rekurse(); 
            },
            error: function(){
                alert(data);
                rekurse(); // recurse, if you'd like.
            }           
        });     

        /* ---------------------------------- */       
   }, 1000);

})();

</script>
</head>

<body onload="rekurse();return false;">

</body>
<html><body
```

and on shift.php, its just like

```
<?PHP
//
CLEARSTATCACHE();
//
$grps = '_';
$offi = $_POST['offi'];
$temp = $offi.'/'.$grps.'*.*';
$arrs = GLOB( $temp  );
$coun = COUNT( $arrs );
//
IF($coun<1):
    ECHO json_encode("ok");
ENDIF;
//
$text = $offi."/call.htm";
$hand = FOPEN( $text, 'w' );
$text = FWRITE( $hand,"\r\n");
$hand = FCLOSE( $hand );
//
$file = $arrs[0];
$hand = FOPEN( $file, 'r' );
$temp = FREAD( $hand, FILESIZE( $file ) );
$hand = FCLOSE( $hand );
//
$arrs = EXPLODE(',',$temp);
IF( COUNT($arrs)>0 ):
    ECHO json_encode($temp);
ELSE:
    ECHO json_encode("ok");
ENDIF;
//
?>
```

What im missed this and sorry about my english

Thank You

Regard
Bambang

Answer (score 0):

Recursive AJAX is a bed idea.
you just check code of your php file and make sure it work's properly then after you call ajax function to get a file name.

First call your php file manually and check the output.

just use code like below don't make it complex..

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,           
        url: 'shift.php',
        data: {offi: 'E:/DataText/OFFICE/BI/FAR1'},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert(data);
        }           
    });
```